# size responsive field in django forms

Tags: python, html, css, django, responsive

I'm making an web application and i wanted to create responsive fields in my forms.
When im visiting my site in small window all my forms fileds stick out of their containers borders.
Example of my html code from login window.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Login  DomainManager</title>
            {% load static %}
            <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
            <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="center">
            <div class="panel panel-info" >
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <center> <h3 class="panel-title">Login</h3> </center>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form method="post" action="{%  url 'login' %}">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                            <p><b>Username: {{ form.username }}</b></p>
                            <p><b> Password: {{ form.password }}</b></p>
                            <center>
                                <p><input type="submit"  value="Login"></p>
                                <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}">
                                <a href="/register" style="color: black">No account? Register</a>
                            </center>

                        {% if form.errors %}
                            <center>
                                <p style="color:#ff0000;">Your login or password is wrong!</p>
                                <p><a href="/accounts/password_reset/" style="color: black">Forgot password?</a></p>
                            </center>
                        {%  endif %}
                        {%  if next %}
                            <p>No access.</p>
                        {% endif %}
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

<style>
    body {
        background-color:#f9f9f9;
    }
    .panel > .panel-heading {
        background-color: #222222;
        color: gray;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .panel-info {
        border-color: #222222;
    }
    .panel-body {
        padding-left: 10%;
        padding-right: 10%;
    }
    div.center {
        margin: 0;
        width: 15%;
        top: 30%;
        left: 50%;
        position: absolute;
        -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -30%);
        transform: translate(-50%, -30%);
    }
</style>
```

i use UserCreationForms and this is how it looks in smaller WebBrowser window:

[image]

Comment: put fields inside `div` and add `row w-25` to the div class